# how to execute git commands in gitlab-ci scripts

Tags: gitlab-ci

I want to change a file and commit changes inside a gitlab-ci pipeline

I tried writing normal git commands in script

```
script:
    - git clone git@gitlab.url.to.project.git
    - cd project file
    - touch test.txt
    - git config --global user.name "${GITLAB_USER_NAME}"
    - git config --global user.email "${GITLAB_USER_EMAIL}"
    - git add .
    - git commit -m "testing autocommit"
    - git push
```

I get cannot find command git or something along those lines, I know it has something to do with tags, but if I try add a git tag it says no active runner. anyone has an idea how to run git commands on gitlab-ci ?

Comment: What is the exact error u get, do u get error like "git: command not found" ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

First you need to make sure you can actually use `git`, so either run your jobs on a `shell` executor located on a system that has `git` or use a `docker` executor and use an image that has `git` installed.

Next problem you will encounter is that you can't push to Git(lab) since you can't enter credentials.

So the solution is to create a ssh keypair and load the ssh private key into your CI environment through [CI/CD variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/), also add the corresponding public key to you [your Git(lab) account](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/).

Source: https://about.gitlab.com/2017/11/02/automating-boring-git-operations-gitlab-ci/

Your `.gitlab-ci.yml` will then look like this:

```
job-name:
  stage: touch
  before_script:
    - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )'
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
    - ssh-add <(echo "$GIT_SSH_PRIV_KEY")
    - git config --global user.name "${GITLAB_USER_NAME}"
    - git config --global user.email "${GITLAB_USER_EMAIL}"
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - cat gitlab-known-hosts >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
  script:
    - git clone git@gitlab.url.to.project.git
    - cd project file
    - touch test.txt
    - git add .
    - git commit -m "testing autocommit"
    - git push
```

Comment: What if I don't want to use my personal credentials? I've asked a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72202780/7850)

Comment: For credentials, it is better to use gitlab project token, put the token in a secret projet variable, and use that in the ci.yml:
git remote set-url origin http://oauth2:$SECRET_TOKEN_FOR_UPDATE_BUILD_IN_CI@$CI_SERVER_HOST/$CI_PROJECT_PATH

Comment: @DavidBonnin, I did have the command git remote set-url origin with the project token used in the url something like this " - git remote set-url origin https://cicd-pipeline:${GITLAB_TOKEN}@gitlab.com/{project_path}" but my pipeline is failing at a merge command asking me "who you are".. any idea why that would be?

Answer (score 3):

Gitlab CI/CD will clone the repository inside the running job automatically. What you need is the git command installed. You could use [bitnami/git](https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/git) image to run the job in a container having the command installed.

This worked for me (trying to verify if a tag is available):

```
tag-available:
stage: .pre
image: bitnami/git:2.37.1
script:
    # list all tags
    - git tag -l
    # check existence of tag "v1.0.0"
    - >
        if [ $(git tag -l "v1.0.0") ]; then
            echo "yes"
        else
            echo "no."
```

If you need to authorize the job agains some gitlab registry (or api) please note that there are some [predefined variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html) for user and password (tokens). For this kind of actions you might be most interested in these variables:

```
$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD
$CI_REGISTRY_USER
$CI_REGISTRY
$CI_REPOSITORY_URL
$CI_DEPLOY_PASSWORD
$CI_DEPLOY_USER
```

The CI_DEPLOY_USER must have a deploy user created and named "gitlab-deploy-token" to have his password loaded in the CI/CD. Read [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/deploy_tokens/index.html#gitlab-deploy-token) more.